# Laravel: One relation, multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relationship

I have a model "User", and each user has "Posts". Now there are different types of posts, like "TextPost", "VideoPost", etc.

I want to get all posts of a user like this:

`$user->posts()->get()`

This should return an array of objects with the correct class, so e.g. an array like this:

`[App\VideoPost{}, App\TextPost{}]`

I tried to use polymorphic relationships as described in the docs, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You should show your relationships and content of `posts` table

Comment: seeing some code would be nice

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a relationship type in Laravel for your specific use case. The easiest thing you can do in this case is create a separate hasMany relationship for each of your post types, and then write a function that returns a combination of all the results.

So you'd end up with something like this in your User class:

```
public function videoPosts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\VideoPost::class);
}

public function textPosts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\TextPost::class);
}

public function getPosts()
{
  return $this->textPosts->concat($this->videoPosts);
}
```

You can then just keep chaining concat calls for every other post type you may want to add.